# If $H$ is a subgroup of a finite goup $G$, is there a subgroup $K$ s.t. $G=HK$ and $|G|=|H||K|$?

Tags: group-theory

$G$ is a finite group $G$, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I know that there must be a $A \subseteq G$, $G=AH$.

However, must there be a subgroup $K$ of $G$ s.t. $G=HK$ and $|G|=|H||K|$?

Comment: No. Take $G = Q_{8}$, and $H = Z(G)$, for instance. More generally, if $H$ is a nontrivial proper subgroup of $G$ which is contained in every nontrivial subgroup of $G$, then there can be no such $K$.

Comment: No. The alternating group $A_5$ is a group $G$ of order $60.$ It has a subgroup $H$ of order $2$ but it has no subgroup $K$ of order $30.$

Comment: Simpler: $A_4$ has a subgroup of order 2, but no subgroup of order 6.

Comment: Even simpler $G=C_4$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $2$. The only choice of $K$ with $G=HK$ is $G$, so $|H||K|>|G|$.

Comment: Each/any of these should be an answer.

Comment: Does this (or similar) property have a name? Something like a "separable group"?

Comment: I've not actually seen this used anywhere, but it is called a Zappa-Szep product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A9p_product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several simple counterexamples have been given in the comments. One of these is: let $G=A_4$, the alternating group on four letters. Then $G$ has order 12, and $G$ has several elements of order 2, each of which generates a subgroup of order 2, but $G$ has no subgroup of order 6.